# IsPointerOverGameObject get the gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I want to know over which object is user pointing it's mouse.

I've found that i can know when he is pointing one (IsPointerOverGameObject), but i can't find the way to get that gameObject.
http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html

Do i really have to manually raycast the UI?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is how you do it, you send a raycast.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
{                    
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
       print(hit.collider.transform.gameObject.name);
}
```

Comment: it's more something like:
`List<RaycastResult> raycastResults = new List<RaycastResult>();
  EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventData, raycastResults);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Event Triggers to detect interaction with UI elements (maybe Pointer Down is what you want?) rather than messing with raycasting here.